# Right side wrap for ribbon does not vertically align

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to make a ribbon for a navbar using bootstrap and my own CSS work. I have the majority of what I need finished, however I cannot seem to make the right side of the ribbon align with the navbar.

(colors purposefully bad to make the example obvious)
[image]

Here's an example of my situation: [JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/UFoRIYex/494)

CSS:

```
nav.navbar {
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), 0 1px 5px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    box-shadow: none;
}

div.ribbon-left {
    left: -13px;
    float: left;
    width: 13px;
    border-right: none;
}

div.ribbon-right {
    width: 13px;
    float: right;
    right: -13px;
    border-left: none;
}

div.ribbon-left, div.ribbon-right {
    position: relative;
    /*background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0, #f8f8f8 100%) repeat-x;*/
    background: white;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 52px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

div.ribbon-top-back {
    z-index: -10;
    border-color: transparent transparent #f0f0f0 transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 13px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    position: relative;
    left: -1px;
    top: -27px;
}

div.ribbon-right > div.ribbon-top-back {
    left: -14px;
}

/* Temporary coloring to make things obvious */
body {
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

.container {
    background-color: #c0a16b;
}

html, body, div.container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

A general idea of the ribbon layout:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="ribbon">
        <div class="ribbon-left">
            <div class="ribbon-top-back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ribbon-content">
            <!-- bootstrap navbar -->
        </div>
        <div class="ribbon-right">
            <div class="ribbon-top-back"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the element align correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some testing, it became apparent that if I wanted the element to be in-line, I would need to declare it before the navbar (seeing as it's `relative` positioning but `float: right`):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="ribbon">
        <div class="ribbon-left">
            <div class="ribbon-top-back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ribbon-right">
            <div class="ribbon-top-back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ribbon-content">
            <!-- bootstrap navbar -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```